How to check the ordering of extrinsic payload for SCALE encoding in polkadot-sdk?
Below is something which I found in the polkadot-js api code
describe('ExtrinsicPayload', (): void => {
  it('has a sane inspect', (): void => {
    // we don't expect this to fail, however it is actually a good
    // reference for the ordering in base Substrate
    expect(new ExtrinsicPayload(registry, { method: tx['timestamp']['set'](0).toHex() } as never).inspect()).toEqual({
      inner: [
        { name: 'method', outer: [new Uint8Array([3, 0, 0])] },
        { inner: undefined, name: 'era', outer: [new Uint8Array([0]), new Uint8Array([0])] },
        { name: 'nonce', outer: [new Uint8Array([0])] },
        { name: 'tip', outer: [new Uint8Array([0])] },
        { name: 'assetId', outer: [new Uint8Array([0])] },
        { name: 'mode', outer: [new Uint8Array([0])] },
        { name: 'specVersion', outer: [new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 0])] },
        { name: 'transactionVersion', outer: [new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 0])] },
        { name: 'genesisHash', outer: [new Uint8Array(32)] },
        { name: 'blockHash', outer: [new Uint8Array(32)] },
        { name: 'metadataHash', outer: [new Uint8Array([0])] }
      ]
    });
  });
});



What is the question now?

@OliverTale-Yazdi How to find the ordering in Polkadot-sdk code? Sorry I should have added

Is my edit the question you wanted to ask? (if not just rephrase or remove it)

@Simson thank you for the edit. I want to know the ordering of extrinsic in the polkadot-sdk code? anywhere I can refer?
I found in polkadot-js api code, but I want to understand where the order is defined in the actual polkadot-sdk source code?

@Simson thats not what Im looking for. Also the edit you did is not correct. Reverted back.

@muddlebee cool, but try to elaborate on the question to make us understand what you want to know

The order of the signed extensions is always configured in the runtime. For Polkadot you for example find it here.
You can also look into other runtimes, they will have a similar block that determines the order.
